# System.CommandLine problem with ArgumentArity

Tags: system.commandline

I've got this RootCommand:

```
var rootCommand = new RootCommand()
            {
                new Argument<string>("search","string to search for")
                ,new Option<string>(new []{"--path","-p"},getDefaultValue:()=>Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"path where to search")
                ,new Option<string[]>(new []{"-f","--files"},"file pattern to match to search in"){ Argument=new Argument<string[]>(getDefaultValue:()=>new[]{"*.*"}){Arity=ArgumentArity.ZeroOrMore} }
            };
```

the option -f is supposed to take zero or more values, but in the handler defined as below:

```
rootCommand.Handler= CommandHandler.Create<string,string,string[]>(async (search,path,filepattern)=> {
```

filepattern is always null, even if I call with, for instance `-f *.cs`.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue was that the argument names don't match the option names

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline) say:

> Camel casing on Main’s parameter names is converted to Posix-style argument names (that is, xCropSize translates to --x-crop-size on the command line).

So this Should work:

```
rootCommand.Handler= CommandHandler.Create<string,string,string[]>(async (search,path,files)=> {
```